# Unable to request from server to my browser using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is wrong with my code i am unbable to get the response on my browser from the server.

```
<form action="server.txt" method="post">
<input id="m_item" type="text" name="m_item"></input>
        <div id="m_item_option">
        </div>
</form>
```

Here is my jquery code below...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#m_item").keyup(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var m_item = $(this).val();
        if(m_item != ""){
            $.ajax({
                url:"validation/sample_mysql_test.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{m_item:m_item},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#m_item_option").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

here is My php mysql code below

```
$data =   $_POST['m_item'];
            $item = '';                 
            $sql = "SELECT itemId, itemName FROM itemlist WHERE itemName like concat('%', :itemName, '%')";
            $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $st->bindValue(":itemName", $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->execute();
            $row = $st->fetchAll();
            //print_r($row);
            if($row > 0){
                foreach($row as $rows){ 
                    $item .= $rows['itemName']."<br/>";
                    //"<option value=" . $item .">". $item ."</option>";                                            
                }
            }
echo $item
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Debug each line starting from the Ajax request down to the php side. You should see the error. Also carefully monitor the network tab.Also the $row array might be empty

Comment: your php has error, that's way your `success` callback function not working. Replace `like concat('%', :itemName, '%')` with `like concat('%', ':itemName', '%')`